# How to make a div with dynamic content automatically scroll to the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, autoscroll

I have googled around and found a few solutions to this problem, but none of them seem to work in my situation.  I have tried hidden inputs to scroll to, that stay at the bottom

```
document.getElementById('scrollToMe').scrollIntoView();
```

I have tried

```
$("#postbox").scrollTop($("#postbox")[0].scrollHeight);
```

and a few others.  Here is my situation

I have a chat room (http://novaplasm.topiacloud.com/Chat).  When you type anything, it enters it into the div "postbox" using Knockout.  Every time you enter new content, it appends it.  I want to make it so you can always see the latest message, without having to scroll yourself.  I can't seem to do this for the life of me.  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Does $("#postbox")[0].scrollHeight return a value more than 0 ?

Comment: @Dilantha I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get a reference to your postbox and chat message div

```
   var pbox = $('#postbox');

   var chat_div = $('<div></div>').attr('class', 'chat_msg').text(msg);
```

Here msg is your chat message

Then you have to scroll down using the 'animate' method like this

```
  chat_div.appendTo(pbox);

   var height = pbox.scrollTop() + pbox.height() +  $('#postbox').filter('.chat_msg:last').scrollTop();

   pbox.animate({'scrollTop' : height}, 1000);
```

Here the animation is happening over 1 sec.

Refer jQuery documentation for more detailed explanations on jQuery methods.

[Live fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kwVFe/)

Comment: How would I customize this to work in my current code?  Would chat div be my "post" class or my "posts" class?  Go to the website and inspect element to see which is which.